# using weakReference and WakHasMap Android bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, android-memory

After making with images:

```
 WeakHashMap<Bitmap, WeakReference<Bitmap>> objReferenciaDebilBitmaps;
 Bitmap imagen = datossss.getImagen();
 objreCReferencias.RegristrarReferenciaDebilBitmap(imagen, objReferenciaDebilBitmaps);
```

my class Creferencias

```
public class CReferencias {


public CReferencias(){

}

public void RegristrarReferenciaDebilBitmap(Bitmap img, WeakHashMap<Bitmap, WeakReference<Bitmap>> objReferenciaDebilBitmaps){
    WeakReference<Bitmap> objrererencia1 = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(img);
    objReferenciaDebilBitmaps.put(img, objrererencia1);

}
```

After using this every time I do  I create an Image, I do not know if it's the right way to use weak references to the bitmap,

but still gives me the problem sigiente

this is my logcat

```
  12-10 13:54:53.523: E/dalvikvm-heap(1211): Out of memory on a 2304016-byte allocation.
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at dep.Agenda.CustomAdapterDetalleEventos.getView(CustomAdapterDetalleEventos.java:558)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2201)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1774)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:705)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:645)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5263)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.widget.AbsListView$TwFlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4156)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
12-10 13:54:53.528: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is lines my adapter

```
    public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View vistaFila =null;

     final  ElementosLinea objelementos;//=null;

        //final ElementosLinea obj;
        //final View auxVistaFila=null;


     LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
             //  LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();


            //LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vistaFila = vi.inflate(R.layout.ll_lineas_lista_detalle_evento_nueva, null);

            //AsignarElementos(vistaFila);

           objelementos = new ElementosLinea();
          AsignarElementos(vistaFila,objelementos);




         vistaFila.setTag(objelementos);
         objelementos.posicion= position;

        }else{
            //vistaFila = vi.inflate(R.layout.ll_lineas_lista_detalles_evento, null);
          vistaFila=convertView;
          objelementos=(ElementosLinea)convertView.getTag();
          objelementos.posicion= position;
       }

        DetalleEvento datossss = arrayDatos.get(position);

        if (datossss.getGusta()==0){

            objelementos.btnMegusta.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.megustagris);
            objelementos.txtMegusta.setText("Me gusta");
        }else{
            objelementos.btnMegusta.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.megustaazul);
            objelementos.txtMegusta.setText("No me gusta"); 
            }


      //llenamos la barra de progreso
    if (datossss.getTipo()==1){//SI ES UN VIDEO

        objelementos.txtTitulo.setText(datossss.getTituloPost());
        objelementos.txtAutor.setText(datossss.getAutor());
        objelementos.txtPost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (datossss.getImagen()!=null){
            Bitmap imagen = datossss.getImagen();
            objreCReferencias.RegristrarReferenciaDebilBitmap(imagen, objReferenciaDebilBitmaps);
             int width = imagen.getWidth();
                int height = imagen.getHeight();
                int newWidth = activiadPricipal.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                int newHeight = newWidth-80;

                float scalarw=((float) newWidth) /width;
                float scalarh=((float) newHeight) /height;

            Matrix ma = new Matrix();
             ma.postScale(scalarw, scalarh);

             Bitmap res = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagen, 0, 0,
                  width, height, ma, true);
        objreCReferencias.RegristrarReferenciaDebilBitmap(res, objReferenciaDebilBitmaps); 
        objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setImageBitmap(res);
        //imagen.recycle();
        //res.recycle();
        objelementos.btnComentarios.setEnabled(true);
        objelementos.pgrprogreso.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }else{


              int newWidth = activiadPricipal.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
              int newHeight = newWidth-80;

              objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setImageBitmap(null);
              objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setMinimumHeight(newHeight);
              objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setMinimumWidth(newWidth);
              objelementos.pgrprogreso.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        objelementos.btnComentarios.setEnabled(false);
        }
        objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        objelementos.btnVerVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        objelementos.txtFecha.setText(datossss.getFecha());
        objelementos.btnVerfoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




    }else{  if (datossss.getTipo()==2){ //SI ES UN POST

        objelementos.txtTitulo.setText(datossss.getTituloPost());
        objelementos.txtAutor.setText(datossss.getAutor());
        objelementos.txtPost.setText(datossss.getTexto());
        objelementos.txtPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setImageBitmap(null);
        objelementos.btnVerVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        objelementos.txtFecha.setText(datossss.getFecha());
        objelementos.btnVerfoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        objelementos.btnComentarios.setEnabled(true);

        objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setMinimumHeight(0);
          objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setMinimumWidth(0);

          objelementos.pgrprogreso.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //rtlCuerpo.set






    }else{//SI ES UNA FOTO

        objelementos.txtTitulo.setText(datossss.getTituloPost());
        objelementos.txtAutor.setText(datossss.getAutor());
        objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        objelementos.btnVerfoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        if (datossss.getImagen()!=null){
        Bitmap imagen = datossss.getImagen();
         objreCReferencias.RegristrarReferenciaDebilBitmap(imagen, objReferenciaDebilBitmaps); 
         int width = imagen.getWidth();
            int height = imagen.getHeight();
            int newWidth = activiadPricipal.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int newHeight = newWidth-80;

            float scalarw=((float) newWidth) /width;
            float scalarh=((float) newHeight) /height;

        Matrix ma = new Matrix();
         ma.postScale(scalarw, scalarh);

         Bitmap res = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagen, 0, 0,
              width, height, ma, true);

         objreCReferencias.RegristrarReferenciaDebilBitmap(res, objReferenciaDebilBitmaps);     
        objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setImageBitmap(res);
        //imagen.recycle();
        //res.recycle();
        objelementos.btnComentarios.setEnabled(true);
        objelementos.pgrprogreso.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
              int newWidth = activiadPricipal.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
              int newHeight = newWidth-80;

              objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setImageBitmap(null);
              objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setMinimumHeight(newHeight);
              objelementos.imgfotoVideo.setMinimumWidth(newWidth);


            objelementos.btnComentarios.setEnabled(false);
            objelementos.pgrprogreso.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        objelementos.txtPost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        objelementos.btnVerVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        objelementos.txtFecha.setText(datossss.getFecha());



    }



    }

    if (datossss.getImagenAvatar()!=null){
         objelementos.imgAvatar.setImageBitmap(datossss.getImagenAvatar());
    }else{
         objelementos.imgAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatarpredeterminado);
    }


     objelementos.txtTitulo.setText(datossss.getTituloPost());



    return vistaFila;



      }
```

the objelementos equivalent viewholder

**that's what I'm doing wrong? I might say, as is the proper way to use weak references for all images and are deleted when I do not need?**

Comment: Instead of weakhashmap you should use lrucache: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Answer (score 1):

The error is  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` here. So if you are using API level greater than 10 then you can use this line `android:largeHeap="true"` in the manifest of your app at application level.